# How do I parent two objects without unparenting another two objects?

Tags: parent

I created a plane. I divided it into lots of segments. I created a 3D object and, when I was happy with it, I duplicated it a bunch of times (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>). Then I went along some of the vertices of my plane and selected, and did hook to new object.

Now when I select a 3D object and then the empty object and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent one to the other that works... For a while. As soon as I parent the next 3D object to the next empty, the first one loses all relationship with its empty.

What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Update. In order to clarify, I reloaded my save and tried to take some screenshots.

[image]

Not parented, right? So, I parent the one on the far right...

[image]

Uh...?

[image]

I don't get it but okay. Let's do number 3. (Select hoop, select empty object)

[image]

Nope...

I am, at this stage, a very baffled newbie. Clearly, I have stuffed up but how and where?

Comment: If I read this right, you're parenting an object (the child) to one of the hooks, then doing the same with a 2nd object to a 2nd hook?   I'm off to my other machine to try this...  Will come back.

Comment: I'm back and have tried just about every way of doing this and can't make it fail.  I'm using vers 2.77a.  Perhaps it's a version problem.  You can have my blend file if you think it will help.

Comment: you should put a screenshot because I'm not sure it's clear enough

Comment: It sounds like you're unable to select and highlite the 2nd Emprty for some reason. When you select the 2nd Empty, does it highlite like it should?  Could it  be possibly be locked out? (the arrow in the outliner, or padlocked in the Dopesheet?)  Is the mouse cursor sitting in the 3D window when you press CTL-P?  Basic questions I know but we haven't your Blend file to look at.

Comment: No, everything selects as it should. Is there a way for me to share the blend file?

Comment: Yes, just open a new tab in your broswer, go to -  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - and upload it.  Cowfilms is supposed to give you a link which you copy/paste into your post.

Comment: It's just dawned on me - if the 3D models you're trying to parent to Hooks were originally duplicates of the first you produced, it could be that they're still linked in some way with the original.  This would explain why the first duplicate (or the original) is losing it's parent when you try to do the same with a copy.  The Outliner should tell you what's what with each duplicate.  Make sure to clear all animation and links with the original.  It sounds like something is tying them all together.  Hope that either helps or sparks a brainwave.